# custom filter - where to write this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model generated by Devise. So, I have before filter authenticate_user.

I have used STI and created 2 more models UserA < User, UserB < User.

User has a field 'type' which determines whether user object is of type 'UserA' or 'UserB'.

I have some controllers in which I want specific filter, like, can be seen only by user type 'UserA' or UserB. So, I want to write a filter like this:

```
def authenticate_usera
    if current_user.type == 'usera'
        return true
    else
        return false
end

def authenticate_userb
    if current_user.type == 'userb'
        return true
    else
        return false
end
```

Question:
So, where should I place this filter code?  And, can I use like this in controller:
     before_filter :authenticate_usera

Also, do I need to use anything like 'require' for that filter to be available in this ?

Comment: `current_user.type == 'usera'` should be a method in your user model

Comment: thanks for that. thats fine with that, whats the answer ? What we write in filter is a different issue, I want to know how to custom authenticate or filter controller.

Comment: This is pretty dependency laden. What does your controller want? It wants to know if the current_user can access something. It doesn't need to know about the type of the user, or anything else. E.g. current_user.can?(:access, an_object) and that'd return whether or not the user can perform that action. E.g. the User model should care about this, not the controller. Check out cancan: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Answer (score 0):

In your `ApplicationController` add the following function:

```
def only_allowed_for(user_type_class)
  unless current_user.is_a?(user_type_class)
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'Access to the page is not allowed'
  end
end
```

In my test I am assuming that through the STI the current user will have the correct class. I am not entirely sure about this (it might depend on how devise creates the user). But you get the picture.

Then, in any controller, you can write the following:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter { |c| c.only_allowed_for(UserA) }

end
```

As you can tell: you can edit for which class access is allowed. 
And this will redirect to root if access is not allowed.